# How to ADD resistance with a push-button (Schematic Incl.)

Tags: switches

Edit: New schematic, my apologies.

**Background:**
The circuit below shows a potentiometer "R1", which is not used until the normally open push-button "S1" is pressed. The second resistor "R2" is not used until the normally open push-button "S2" is pressed.

The orange square just represents a PCB I didn't design with components irrelevant to the issue.

**Problem:**
Obviously if both S1 and S2 are pressed at the same time, then R1 and R2 are in parallel. I need to make S2 *increase* the overall resistance even if S1 is currently pressed. *The specific impedance is not too important, I just can't have R1 in parallel subtracting from the impedance of R2.*

Basically I need S2 to override S1, either by somehow adding R2 in series with R1, or by having R2 replace R1 in the current.

**Conditions:**
S1 pressed: R1 only
S2 pressed: R2 only
S1+S2 pressed: at least R2 or both R1+R2
Default State: No current

Can this be done using only passive components and push-buttons?

[image: schematic]

Comment: Wow I used the wrong schematic. Thank you. I was having problems with the website.

Comment: "Obviously if both S1 and S2 are pressed at the same time, then R1 and R2 are in parallel" - incorrect - how can anything be in parallel with R1 unless your circuit board (orange) is a dead short? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry! I originally had multiple schematics but there is no preview or formatting tool showing up so my post was messed up.

I fixed the schematic now, but it's too late. I think I should flag it for deletion and try it again later...

Comment: Bort, it's fixed no, no need to delete.

Comment: @Passerby but now half the responses are referring to a different circuit!

Comment: The schematic in the question doesn't make much sense. The OP wants a specific behaviour, if he was able to describe that behaviour using a schematic then he would also have a solution but since he doesn't the schematic will be showing a different thing than what is described in the text. I think the OP should describe clearly the behaviour in each possible condition 1) both switch open, 2) only s1 closed , 3) only s2 closed, 4) both closed.

Comment: @alexan_e The schematic has already been fixed. I'll try to be more specific with another edit if it's too hard to understand.

Comment: @bort What do you mean fixed? Does this mean that the schematic is the actual solution you were searching for? If so then it should have been posted as an accepted reply to show that this question has been solved.

Comment: @alexan_e he means that the schematic and description in the question match each other AND what the he currently has the problem with.

Comment: @alexan_e The schematic is fixed, IE: The wrong schematic is NOT shown anymore. What you see is what I have, not what I want. Originally I had posted the wrong images, so I fixed the post. None of my browsers are showing me the preview box or formatting tool, and so it's difficult for me to post. Again - my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I need S2 to override S1, either by somehow adding R2 in series with R1, or by having R2 replace R1 in the current.

This can be done, with a button that does both NC and NO (Essentially a momentary SPDT). A toggle switch illustrates it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNU4NM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see in the top illustration, The Default state of SW2 is to R1. But SW1 is in the way. So SW1 must be pressed, and the resistance of R1 is seen at the output. When SW2 is pressed, SW1 and R1 are completely removed from the circuit, so only R2 is seen at the output, with no parallel load.

But since you say that series resistance is not an issue, just move things around, and you can keep using a simple NO Pushbuttons. With R2 (R4) first, pressing SW1 Results in R2 + R1 in series, while SW2 results in Just R2 (Because R1 is shorted out). Though it does depend on if the orange circuit logic can be changed to handle that setup.

Oh, and if you want to get real fancy, a momentary (or not) On/Off/On switch can be used, replacing SW2 in the top circuit, while getting rid of SW1. Since it's still a SPDT type switch, there will never be any parallel load, since it has a middle off, it still allows neither circuit to be activated, AND it prevents the user from activating both circuits at the same time. Logically, A, B, Off, not A, B, A+B, Off.

Comment: Frankly my brain is fried today, but I don't see a way that it can done any other way it can be done with just two NO buttons, without adding a (relative) ton of logic or extra chips.

Comment: Your top illustration is ideal, however I've been unable to find a simple double throw push-button. I'm sure they exist, but all I've come across are ones that are basically a modified toggle button, requiring a very deep press and strenuous "toggle-like click", making rapid presses impracticable. 

Your second circuit would not work because R4 is always part of the circuit, and the potentiometer would never register.

Comment: @Bort The pot would register, based on the actual resistances of R4 and the Pot. 1k R4 + 10k Pot = 11k output resistance. The orange circuit will need to know what values matter and how. But as for the spdt push buttons, a very common version of them are used in arcade machine buttons. VERY VERY small physical resistance and VERY VERY good at human rate rapid pressing. Google "microswitch".

Comment: Thanks again, I'll look for those buttons locally but I'll probably have to get them online. Also what I was implying was that the potentiometer would not register properly in the orange circuit because I did not design it and cannot change it to process those values.

Comment: @bort in that case, yea, it would require a spdt. Seriously, look into microswitches. They provide great push button SPDT NO/NC action and will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Edit, based on clarified information.

You can use a two pole pushbutton S2 as shown.

S1 pressed R1
S2 pressed R2
S1+S2 pressed R2

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZEzoa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The problem with that configuration is that S2 doesn't have any effect unless S1 is already pressed and I'm not sure if this is what the OP want or he is asking for the buttons to be able to work individually.

Comment: @alexan_e I don't see any other way to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

Just try out the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flknDm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

SW1 is a spdt momentary switch and SW2 is a dpdt momentary switch. The four resistors correspond to the four possible switch configurations. Assuming that SW1 and SW2 are pictured in their default (unpressed) position:

- R1 when SW1 and SW2 are not pressed
- R2 when SW1 is not pressed and SW2 is pressed
- R3 when SW1 is pressed and SW2 is not pressed
- R4 when SW1 is pressed and SW2 is pressed

For your case just choose \$\text{R1}=\infty\$ i.e. remove it, R2 = your R2, R3 = your R1, R4 = your R1 plus your R2. You will use one resistor more but in my opinion this system is simpler to understand. Of course i assumed that your resistor won't need to be changed, i.e. they are not connected by a user so you need to actually find a way to sum them.